# Generating classes at runtime in yii framework is a bad idea?

Tags: php, yii

Let's assume that we have module called 'UsersModule' with the following model in it:

```
class User extends CActiveRecord
{
    // Some code here
}
```

We use this module in different applications and some time we want to extend User model to add some custom methods or properties to it. More over, often we want to change tables in database to store this new properties in it. But we don't want to change code in the UsersModule itself because it comes from the master repository (GitHub for ex.) and when we fix some bugs in it we want to simply update this module from repository in all our projects. At the same time we want to save custom changes made for the projects. So we have the following idea:

In UsersModule.php we do the following:

```
class UsersModule extends CWebModule
{
    public $usersBaseClass = 'UsersBase';
}
```

In Users.php:

```
$extendClass = Yii::app()->getModule('users')->usersBaseClass;
$version = '1.0';


$usersFile = Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.runtime').'/Users_extends_'.$extendClass.'_v'.$version.'.php';
if(!file_exists($usersFile)) {
    $code =<<<PHP
<?php
/**
 * This is the model class for table "{{users}}".
 */
class Users extends {$extendClass}
{
    /**
     * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
     * @param string \$className active record class name.
     * @return Users the static model class
     */
    public static function model(\$className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model(\$className);
    }
}
PHP;
    file_put_contents($usersFile, $code);
}
if(!class_exists('Users', flase))
    require_once($usersFile);
```

Also we introduce UsersBase.php:

```
class UsersBase extends CActiveRecord
{
    // All base Users model logic is here
}
```

So when we use Users class somewhere in our application our code in Users.php generates real Users class that extends desired base class. In each project when we want to extend our Users model we can do the following:

In configs/main.php of the project:

```
'modules' =>
    'users => array(
        'usersBaseClass' => 'MyUsers'
    )
```

And also we add MyUsers.php some where in our application:

```
class MyUsers extends UsersBase
{
    // All the custom logic goes here
}
```

So my question is:

Is it a good idea to generate classes automatically in runtime or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Genrating php code during runtime could work, but not the best solution imho. You should use some kind of table inheritance.

More info:

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/198/single-table-inheritance/
http://learnyii.blogspot.hu/2012/04/yii-table-inheritance-single-active.html